# YouTube Connection test - jQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube

I'm loading a YouTube iframe player and would like to provide a fallback flash player if the person's computer can't connect to YouTube from their workplace. Is there a way to check with a jquery conditional statement if the person's computer is blocked from YouTube or not? 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using jQuery to load the iframe?

Comment: I could; I'm actually using some php to load the youTube ID as variable in the iframe. The iframe is in a div that I could empty and load an object into with an ajax call. I'm open to any ideas and can workaround a different solution using php. I guess I just ned some way to check if the computer can connect to YouTube at all; any method using php or jQuery would work for me. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works... but there are a couple of caveats: if YouTube is "blocked" and the blocker happens to return a valid response, it's possible that the success will be a false positive. Also, it's possible that "error" will not get called if the response causes jQuery to have an internal error because the returned dataType wasn't, in fact, jsonp.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?alt=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    },
});
```

Comment: Is there a way with php to test a server connection? I currently have a solution which uses actionscript to catch the player load error using the chromeless api, which then moves it to different frame which loads a flash flv player instead. If actionscript can load the chromeless player and detect a load error, then I'm convinced that php or javascript can do the same thing. I'm just trying to make a solution that doesn't require me to make a custom swf; I'd rather use php and or javascript. Any toher ideas, the ajax load error didn't work that well for me. Thanks for your time, Caleb.

Comment: The ajax request should bring up a statusCode 404; I am trying to use the code you provided with the statusCode response, any ideas?

Comment: The problem with using PHP is that you won't know whether the client has access or not; just your server... so that's not useful information for you. -- As for the JS, the current implementation of JSONP in jQuery is very limited and doesn't give you a great deal of information... I believe that success is the only callback that can tell you the status of the call: success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)